# bootstrap modal popup not working when base path include

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap (3.0.2) modal won't show up. I've tried different buttons, links and all that but it simply won't show up. I appreciate any help!

```
<a onclick="open_popup('login');">lo</a> 
<script>
    function open_popup(popup) {
        var data_str = 'popup=' + popup;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "exam.php",
            data: data_str,
            success: function() {}
        });
    };
</script>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login_pop" style="display:none"></button>
<div class="login_pop" id="login_pop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="login_modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: show some code to see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$("#login_pop").modal("show");` to show the modal through code. Try below code.

```
<script>    
function open_popup(popup) { 
    $("#login_pop").modal("show");
    var data_str='popup='+popup; 
    $.ajax({ type:"GET", cache:false, 
            url:"exam.php", 
            data:data_str, 
            success:function(){ } 
    });
};
</script>

<a onclick="open_popup('login');">lo</a> 
<div class="modal fade" id="login_pop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog"> 
        <div class="login_modal-dialog"> 
            <div class="modal-content"> 
                <div class="modal-body"> Hello world!! </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QmSFP/)